# What value of surface gravity does Möbius have in the Sonic games (esp. w.r.t. ver. 1991)?

Tags: sega-genesis, sonic-the-hedgehog-series

I'm trying to compare/contrast the surface gravity of Sonic's Möbius with that of Marioworld.  There's an excellent article [1] that analyzed Marioworld's surface gravity across several games, wherein the mean average turned out to be 7.51(-) g.  In trying to find similar material on Möbius, I've so far found only some material for generic differences between the games [2] and Source engine gravity [3] (after which I broadened my search to Sega Genesis's gravity in general, but no luck so far); Googling quite a few terms has been singularly unforthcoming.

I'm not asking in order to write code for game development.  I'm curious about it  for a much more mundane reason: I'm writing a fanfic in which Sonic noticed the difference immediately upon arrival.  This means that I don't require 5 SD of accuracy (my OCD would love that, of course), but would like more than my own ballpark guesswork.

---

**Sources cited:**

[1] https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2007/mariogravity.shtml 
[2] [What are the different versions of Sonic the Hedgehog (1991) and what differs between them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188895/what-are-the-different-versions-of-sonic-the-hedgehog-1991-and-what-differs-be) 
[3] [What is the gravity model in Source engine games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3249/what-is-the-gravity-model-in-source-engine-games)

Comment: I've gone over the title and question and compared them with the question-asking standards, but I can't figure out what the 2 down-votes (out of 6 views) are for.  2/6 means that there's clearly something wrong with my question.  Could someone clarify how I could improve whatever is wrong with my question?

Comment: Hi @charles.  A lot of users here just don't like what they deem as 'trivia' questions.  That would be my guess.

Comment: Worrisome, and a bit of a shame, but understandable I suppose.  If that's it, then I hope that I don't run into too many more drive-by-trivia-haters.  Given your profile, I'm guessing that you'd likely have spotted and mentioned any errata or formal faux pas in the question.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: To be honest, considering neither of the down-voters gave a reason as to why they did down vote, I assume @BunsGlazing's answer is probably what it is. This question does seem perfectly fine however, and I hope you get the answer you want, Charles.